# Filtering points against polygon

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I am able to run the following polygon filter against my points and it will correctly filter out my points in POSTGIS="2.4.4 r16526"

```
select propertypost_propertypost.*
From propertypost_propertypost
where st_contains(
  'POLYGON((1616523 -172630,1618559 -170395,1612691 -169037,1610057 -170554,1609857 -175464,1611294 -176382,1616523 -172630))',
  propertypost_propertypost.location)
```

however when I run it in Linux with POSTGIS="2.4.3 r16312", it first give me  the following error

**"ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries"**

so I would fix it as

```
  st_polygon('POLYGON((1616523 -172630,1618559 -170395,1612691 -169037,1610057 -170554,1609857 -175464,1611294 -176382,1616523 -172630))',4326),
  propertypost_propertypost.location)
```

then I get this error:

**"function st_polygon(unknown, integer) is not unique"**

so I fixed it as

```
where st_contains(
  st_polygon('POLYGON((1616523 -172630,1618559 -170395,1612691 -169037,1610057 -170554,1609857 -175464,1611294 -176382,1616523 -172630))',4326)::geometry,
  propertypost_propertypost.location)
```

but this error wont go away,

I was wondering how I could get rid of this error

Comment: As specified in this link, http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygon.html ST_Polygon can be created from the LineString type...be careful...

Comment: -172630 is not a valid latitude, so these coordinates are not in WGS84 decimal degrees (4326). I recommend `ST_GeomFromText()` for WKT conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the geometry and to assign it the **proper** SRID (which is **NOT** 4326).

In your original query, the geometry is automatically casted from `text` to `geometry`. Using `St_SetSRID` (or `st_polygon`), the cast cannot be automatically done so you need to force it using `::geometry`.

```
select st_asText(
  St_SetSRID( 
     'POLYGON((1616523 -172630,1618559 -170395,1612691 -169037,1610057 -170554,1609857 -175464,1611294 -176382,1616523 -172630))'::geometry,
      3857)
 );
```

The complete query would therefore be

```
select propertypost_propertypost.*
From propertypost_propertypost
where st_contains(
  St_SetSRID( 
         'POLYGON((1616523 -172630,1618559 -170395,1612691 -169037,1610057 -170554,1609857 -175464,1611294 -176382,1616523 -172630))'::geometry,
          3857),
  propertypost_propertypost.location)
```